# Unknown USB & Can't create a partition

Tags: partitioning, usb, format

First, I wanted to format a USB drive and I activate the erase option by mistake.I interrupted the process by click on cancel button.
[USB Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UHAq.png)
I tried to format the drive using the option button and i got the message in the image below.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHdKS.png)
I opened Gparted software in order to create a partition because I assumed that I deleted the USB partition by mistake. and i got the error in the image below.
[Gparted message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIrKQ.png)
Hopefully I can find a solution to my issue.

Comment: I suggest that you try according to this link: [Postrequisites - restore the USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Postrequisites_-_restore_the_USB_stick)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted)